# How do I change from one fragment or activity to another fragment or activity while using a NavigatorDrawer?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

Sorry, but my question is more complex than what I have asked.  I am new to Java and Android, and this whole NavigationDrawer thing is beating me down, but I am determined to figure it out.  I downloaded the sample code from Android with nav drawer example, and I have deleted and added minor changes to fit preferences.  Basically, using the code provided to me, I cannot figure out how to change to a different activity/fragment.  Should I use another fragment like the example has shown or do I need to create a new Java class that extends an intent and create the corresponding xml layout?  Once that is determined, do I create a switch case in the fragment class that was created to cycle through its corresponding fragment/activity?  Or do I place a switch case in the selectItem() method?  I have been working on this same problem for 8 days now and have finally decided to ask for help after exhausting all of my resources.  Thanks for any help.  Again, I'm not looking for someone to code for me, I only need help in understanding the questions I have asked and where my code will need to be placed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] choices;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        choices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choices_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, choices));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        /*
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_websearch:
                // create intent to perform web search for this planet
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
                // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }*/
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);

        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new ChoicesFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ChoicesFragment.ARG_CHOICES_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(choices[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows its appropriate layout
     */
    public static class ChoicesFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_CHOICES_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public ChoicesFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view_fragment, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_CHOICES_NUMBER);
            String available_choices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choices_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(available_choices.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                    "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(available_choices);
            return rootView;
        }
    }// end ChoicesFragment class
}// end MainActivity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted (I can't compile it and try it now), I believe the intention of the sample is to use fragment when a choice is selected on the navigation drawer. Then you would put a case statement in selectItem() to determine which fragment should be shown.

So for example, if you have two choices (say "Show Red Colour" and "Show Blue Colour"), you would create a "RedFragment" class extending "ChoicesFragment", and a "BlueFragment" class extending "ChoicesFragment". Each of them would use their own XML layout. You can then create a fragment object (say "redFragment" and "blueFragment") for each of them in the onCreate() method.

Then, in the selectItem() method, you have a if/case statement to say if position is 0, then you would show the red fragment with:

```
...
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, redFragment).commit();
...
```

and similarly for blue fragment.

HTH.

Comment: Glad it helped - welcome to the world of Android programming where hours can be spent trying to figure things out :-)

Comment: I added 4 more fragments and instead of creating their objects in the onCreate() method, I instantiated them in the onItemClick method and just replaced the content frame with their respective xml layouts.  Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some problem understanding abstraction levels and i will try to help with that.

Activities are entry points for your app, top level. The best approach is to use fragments and not activites, since fragments are at a lower level of abstraction, fragments are just pieces of activities.

Build all of your views in fragments and then put them on an activity, unless you really need a bigger level of abstraction depending on what your application does.

I do not see the need to create a class extending intent, etc. etc.

what i would is to add the navigation drawer as a fragment and put it in an activity, and the rest of the app should be fragments as well handled by the navigation drawer.

Or the navigation drawer can be part of the activity and the rest of the views fragments that depend from this activity.

Hope this helps to clear your mind.. sorry for not sharing code.. good luck